# mostrar valor maximo cuando coincida id de 2 tablas mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

Tengo 2 tablas las cuales las 2 tienen un id, una de las tablas tiene valores numéricos, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando coincida el id entre las 2 tablas me muestre el valor máximo de la tabla que tiene los valores (ya que hay varios valores que se van incrementando).

tabla 1:

```
id,
nombre,
oferta
```

tabla 2:

```
id,
descripcion
```

Tengo algo así que no anda, ¿en dónde le estaré errando?

```
select T1.name,T1.bid,T1.date,T2.post_title FROM `$table_name` T1
  left join `$table_name1` T2
    on T1.auction_id=T2.ID
   and T1.bid = (select max(T3.bid)
                               from `$table_name` T3
                              where T3.auction_id=T2.ID)
```

Lo que yo necesito es que cuando el id de tabla 1 coincida con la id de la tabla 2 me muestre la oferta máxima que haya y junto a ella el nombre, la oferta de la tabla 1 y seguido a eso la descripción de la tabla 2.

---

VERSION 2 :

Adjunto código resulto ,muchas gracias Ivan :

```
select bid,name,post_title,date from 
( select a.*, b.post_title, row_number() over
(partition by b.id order by a.bid desc) as rn 
from $table1 a right join $table2 b on b.id = a.auction_id ) 
x where rn = 1 and name IS NOT NULL and  order by date desc
```

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres conseguir que la union de dos tablas te de un resultado debes hacerlo con `INNER JOIN` ya que esto te va a dar la union entre las dos tablas, si usas un `LEFT JOIN` te va a dar todos los datos que estan en la tabla 1 pero que no necesariamente estan en la tabla 2.

Tomando eso en cuenta puedes hacer tu consulta bajo el siguiente esquema

```
SELECT MAX(column) 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
```

Con la información que dejaste es la respuesta que te puedo dar, si brindas mas información yo o alguien de la comunidad puede dar una mejor respuesta.

## Edición

```
SELECT MAX(tabla1.oferta) AS 'Oferta Maxima',tabla1.nombre AS Nombre,tabla2.descripcion AS Descripcion
    FROM table1 
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
    GROUP BY tabla1.id;
```

## Edición 2

```
SELECT MAX(tabla1.oferta) AS 'Oferta Maxima',tabla1.nombre AS Nombre,tabla2.descripcion AS Descripcion
        FROM table1 
        INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
        ORDER BY tabla1.oferta DESC
        GROUP BY tabla1.id;
```

Esto te deberia regresar la oferta maxima por cada indicie de la tabla 1, el nombre de quien lo oferto y la descripcion

## Edicion 3

Considerando que se busca el maximo por articulo indiscrimadamente del usuario se hizo la oferta se procede con lo siguiente, primero se considera el siguiente diagrama entidad relacion de las tablas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez que consideramos eso entendemos que el `idtable1` es el mismo dato en ambas tablas, por lo cual podemos empezar a hacer la consulta que se basa en el `INNER JOIN` de una subqueri para delimitar los maximos por tipo

```
SELECT table2.Id AS ID,table2.post_title AS Articulo,A.bid AS Oferta,table2.name AS Nombre
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.Id = table1.auction_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT auction_id AS id, MAX(bid) as bid FROM table1 GROUP BY auction_id) A ON table2.Id = A.id AND table1.bid = A.bid
```

Considerando los siguientes datos de prueba

```
tabla 1:

auction_id | Bid | Name

123 $400 juan

124 $300 pedro

123 $700 lucas

tabla2:

Id | post_title

123 televisor

124 heladera
```

Obtenemos la siguiente salida

```
ID         Articulo   Oferta  Nombre
'123'     'Televisor' '700', 'Lucas'
'124'     'Heladera'  '300', 'Pedro'
```

Con esto hemos obtenido el maximo ofertado para cada articulo.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109027/discussion-on-answer-by-ivan-hernandez-aguilar-mostrar-valor-maximo-cuando-coinc).

Comment: @JesusVitali prueba a entrar en la sala de chat enlazada arriba.

Answer (score 0):

Por ese `GROUP BY` que te veo utilizar, creo que buscas la mejor oferta para cada producto:

```
SELECT c1.bid,name,port_title
  FROM tabla1 JOIN (
    SELECT auction_id,MAX(bid) bid
      FROM tabla1 GROUP BY 1  
  ) c1 USING(auction_id,bid)
  JOIN tabla2 ON auction_id=id
  ORDER BY bid DESC;
```

Si sólo quieres la oferta más alta del total de productos añádele un `LIMIT 1` al final.

Aporto el dataset para las comprobaciones:

```
CREATE TABLE tabla1(
  auction_id int,
  bid float,
  `name` varchar(31)
  );
INSERT INTO tabla1 (auction_id, bid, name) VALUES
  (123,400,'juan'),
  (124,300,'pedro'),
  (123,700,'lucas');
CREATE TABLE tabla2(
  id int,
  port_title varchar(31)
  );
INSERT INTO tabla2 (id, port_title) VALUES
  (123,'televisor'),
  (124,'heladera');
```

El resultado obtenido es:

```
700 lucas   televisor
300 pedro   heladera
```

Recuerda que, en una consulta de totales (y las de agrupamiento lo son), si no aplicas una función de totales (`MAX`, `MIN`, `SUM`, `COUNT`, etc) sobre el campo que proyectas,  obtendrás el primer valor que se encuentre en ese campo.

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.